# How to add username and password in WebService body and get token

Tags: ios, swift

I am working on swift and facing issue for fetching token from the server. I tried to solved it but in iOS it always fails. I put the api in hurl.it and Add header content type: Application/json, but I don't know how to add payload value : `payload--{\"username\": \"username\",\"password\": \"userpassword\"}` in Webservice request.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can set your payload data in httpbody of Request Like Below Code.

```
var dicParameter : NSDictionary = ["username": "username","password":"password"]
                var reqData : NSData = JSONSerialization.data(withJSONObject: dicParameter, options: JSONSerialization.WritingOptions.init(rawValue: 0))

                var request : URLRequest = URLRequest.init(url: "url")
                request.httpBody = reqData
```